# Why 4 memory address are needed for an int variable -4 bytes- if a memory address is 4 bytes?

Tags: c

Address for `array[0]`: 008FFE14

Address for `array[1]`: 008FFE18

Code example:

```
int main() {
  int array[2] = {1, 2};
  printf("%p\n", &(array[0]));
  printf("%p\n", &(array[1]));
  printf("Integer size: %d\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("Word size: %d\n", sizeof(void*));
}
```

Code output:

```
008FFE14
008FFE18
Integer size: 4
Word size: 4
```

Comment: [don't put code/text output in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Most modern architectures use byte-addressed memory

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re confused about? Did you expect something else to happen?

Comment: On a 32-bit operating system, a pointer will be 32 bits in size - I.e. 4 bytes. On a 64-bit operating system, pointers are 64 bits in size. This is part of what defines a 32- or 64-bit operating system. If you're asking something other than this, please clarify it.

Comment: The question is a bit vaguely worded, but I think the answer you are looking for is that memory is byte-indexed rather than word-indexed.  So what you are seeing is that the integer is taking four bytes, not four words.

Comment: Note also that the proper `printf()` format specifier for a `size_t` value, such as the result of `sizeof()`, is `%zu`, not `%d`:  `printf("Word size: %zu\n", sizeof(void*));`

Comment: What is your home mailing address? How many characters does it take to address a post-card that can be sent through the mail?  What if the post-card only says "Hello" (5 characters)?  Does your mailing address require more than 5 characters?  I think that 4 bytes, to address 4294967296 bytes of memory is fantastic!

Comment: What you are calling "word size" you should think more like "pointer size".

Comment: A better analogy might be: If a glass is only half full, why doesn't it automatically shrink to half the size? Because the fixed size of the glass was specified by those who made the it. If you didn't need such a big glass to hold your drink, then pick a smaller glass.

Comment: You want to read and learn what "*pointer arithmetics*" is and how it works in C.

Comment: To be clear: The size of a pointer and the size of an `int` are not specified to be the same.  Either one may be wider than the other.  On rare machines `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(int*)`.  Good code does not need to make the assumptions anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your confusion.

How much a pointer (memory address) takes has nothing to do with data types it points to (`int`, `char` etc.)

**The size of a pointer** determines how many locations in memory are addressable. Modern system architectures are byte addressable. This means a memory address is the address of a byte.

E.g.

- with a 1-byte pointer (8 bits) there are `2^8 = 256` addressable bytes. Not very useful.
- with a 2-byte pointer (16 bits) there are `2^16 = 65,536` addressable bytes.
- with a 4-byte pointer (32 bits) there are `2^32 = 4,294,967,296` addressable bytes. That is about 4 GiB of addressable memory.
- with a 8-byte pointer (64 bits) there are `2^64 = 18446744073709551616` addressable bytes. That is about 16 EiB (exbibytes).

As you can see the size of a pointer determines how much memory is addressable. It has nothing to do with what data occupies that memory.

**The size of a data type** determines how many bytes that data type occupies in memory. For instance, an `int` on some systems occupies 32 bits of memory. That is 4 bytes, i.e. 4 addressable memory locations. This is not affected in any way by the size of total memory addressable. It is not affected by the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why 4 memory address are needed for an int variable -4 bytes- if a memory address is 4 bytes?

Because the same memory that might store `int` (sized 4 bytes) also needs to be able to to store `char`s (sized 1 byte).